# Are such field extensions always separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> I am trying to construct a ***finite*** field extension $L/K$ of prime characteristic $p$, such that $\gcd([L:K],p)=1$, and that has an inseparable element.

Trying to construct an example of such extension, I could only find infinite extensions and extensions where $\gcd([L:K],p)\neq1$, but I can neither prove that the mentioned conditions define a separable extension.

please help :)

Comment: If you can show the composition of fields as a separable and purely inseparable extension, you'll see such a thing is impossible.

Comment: I am not sure I got it...

Comment: Purely inseparable extensions are of the form $K(x)$ where $x^{p^n}\in K$ for some $n$.